# not able to add 2 no.'s in java script and add value to label

Tags: javascript, vb.net

Guys I have a java script code where on radio button click I am setting text of label the no. associated with radio button and if again another  radio button is clicked I am adding its corresponding no. with the previous text of label and setting new sum as label text.

My Code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function getIndex(index)
        {
          //  alert('You have Selected Flight Number:' + index);
            var lbltext = document.getElementById('lblAmount').Text;

             if (lbltext != null) {

                 document.getElementById('lblAmount').innerHTML = (parseFloat(lbltext) + (parseFloat(index)).toString();

             }

             else {

                 document.getElementById('lblAmount').innerHTML =  (parseFloat(index)).toString();

             }
        }
    </script>
```

This code isnot working dont know where I am wrong.

Comment: And your question is....?

Answer (score 0):

This code is fine just need to fix a syntax error in line 9 a close bracket ')' is missing just before .toString()! I have edited Please check if it works for you

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function getIndex(index)
    {
      //  alert('You have Selected Flight Number:' + index);
        var lbltext = document.getElementById('lblAmount').Text;

         if (lbltext != null) {
                                                                                  //here i edit
             document.getElementById('lblAmount').innerHTML = (parseFloat(lbltext) + (parseFloat(index))).toString();

         }

         else {

             document.getElementById('lblAmount').innerHTML =  (parseFloat(index)).toString();

         }
    }
</script>
```

//best of luck :)

Comment: Sumit I dont know what is wrong with my code I am not able to get label text.I modified my code like this:                                 var x = document.getElementById('lblAmount').Text;
             alert(x + '');    but not able to get text of lblAmount.